# remove specific substring from a string and split it with numeric values

Tags: javascript, string, split, nodes

Here is what I have done:

```
var validArray = ["benson","basil","tiger","cocoa","pepper"];
var string = "benson prince 40, basil a 30, cocoa 40, tiger 30 and pepper asd 20";
var splitString = string.split(/\d+/g);
splitString = splitString.map(v => v.trim());
let realArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < splitString.length - 1; i++){
    if(validArray.includes(splitString[i])){
        realArray.push(splitString[i]);
    }
}
console.log(realArray);
```

and I am getting an empty array. If I remove ',', 'and' from the string it will give me an array with ['cocoa','tiger'] which is the actual output I wanted.

I want to get the output

```
['cocoa','tiger']
```

from the string

```
"benson prince 40, basil a 30, cocoa 40, tiger 30 and pepper asd 20".
```

Please help me figure out a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the comma into the regex as optional character `/\d+,?/g` the `?` means 0 or one of the character before it.

```js
var validArray = ["benson","basil","tiger","cocoa","pepper"];
var string = "benson prince 40, basil a 30, cocoa 40, tiger 30 and pepper asd 20";
var splitString = string.split(/\d+,?/g);
splitString = splitString.map(v => v.trim());
let realArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < splitString.length - 1; i++){
    if(validArray.includes(splitString[i])){
        realArray.push(splitString[i]);
    }
}
console.log(realArray);
```

You could also use the [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to get the correct items instead of the for loop.

```js
const validArray = ["benson", "basil", "tiger", "cocoa", "pepper"];
const string = "benson prince 40, basil a 30, cocoa 40, tiger 30 and pepper asd 20";
const splitString = string.split(/\d+,?/g).map(value => value.trim());

const realArray = splitString.filter(item => validArray.includes(item));

console.log(realArray);
```

Or instead of splitting the string just search it for the words in the validArray

```js
const validArray = ["benson", "basil", "tiger", "cocoa", "pepper"];
const string = "benson prince 40, basil a 30, cocoa 40, tiger 30 and pepper asd 20";

const realArray = validArray.filter(item => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${item} \\d+`);
  return string.search(regex) > -1;
});

console.log(realArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single pattern once and capture the word in front of the digits in a group. Then check if the group value exists in the `validArray`

```
(\w+) \d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3RkTS9/1)

For example

```js
const validArray = ["benson", "basil", "tiger", "cocoa", "pepper"];
const realArray = [];
const regex = /(\w+) \d+/g;
const str = `benson prince 40, basil a 30, cocoa 40, tiger 30 and pepper asd 20`;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (validArray.includes(m[1])) realArray.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(realArray);
```